# Boot into recovery without Volume Key

Tags: recovery-mode, 9.0-pie, volume-buttons

My Android 9 Phone is stuck in bootloop. It is rooted.
My phone Vol Down Key is broken.

Is there a way to boot into recovery without using vol button.
(similar questions only had device specific queries or working phones to use adb or apps)

Comment: vol up key - fastboot oem reboot recovery or fastboot boot recovery.img

Comment: its emui - huawei - does not support reboot to recovery from fastboot